# Where to go for ebook suggestions?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, publishing, sales, website

I'm aware of Goodreads but would be interested in recommendations for where to go for book recommendations, across categories.  Certainly there were many articles and lists of books from the end of the year, but I'd be more interested in discussion forums.

I'm not entirely adverse to advertisements, but more interested in what books *people* suggest and discuss online.  Tastes vary, of course, and algorithms have their place as well (or AI if you prefer).

To take one website at random:  the Gutenberg press.  In theory a fantastic idea.  Yet whenever I've looked at their website it's just a needle in a haystack.  I'm sure they have an official blog or announcement system, but I'd be more interested in *discussion* or *review*.  Not [specific](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/qvq99b/how-to-download-the-books-that-just-entered-the-public-domain) to the Gutenberg press, again, conceptually interesting, but just looking for things to read.

(I'm a bit Kindle-centric having drunk the Amazon DRM kool-aid, so that would be my preference for focus should that be an issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't necessarily endorse using it for all your reading, but there are some fine subreddits to suggest book titles. https://www.reddit.com/r/suggestmeabook/ . Also check out the booklists subreddit. Also, [fivebooks.com](https://fivebooks.com/) is creating a whole universe of book suggestions by subject area (though more for academic topics). Finally, I agree with what you are saying about Gutenberg. I've been volunteering as a proofreader, and we've been digitalizing a series of books (BOOK REVIEW DIGEST) which provides useful summaries of books. Most are still in process, but I have a feeling that these summaries will be incorporated into the book pages eventually. Finally, if you don't know it, the [PG Bookshelf page](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:Bookshelf) is good for finding books on a certain topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really too broad and unprecise to respect the usual
rules of Stack-Exchange.  However, I will try to answer it in a way
consistent with such rules.

There are many places where books are discussed, but they are usually
specialized in some way. And no one is going to list the
possibilities, not here.

My best advice is for you to search the web with a generaly search
engine, for comments on books or authors you have been interested
in. This should occasionally lead you to sites that have commented
these books or authors.  Then you can explore the site to see what
else they offer and suggest, and whether you want to use it as a
comment and reference source.

We all differ in our tastes and ways of doing things, and no one can
really do that for you.

You comment on Gutenberg Press does not carry a link (which it
should have). I tried to see which site you mean, but found only
Project Gutenberg. Its purpose is not to suggest e-books, but to make
them available.

The choice of a retailer (Amazon) is a strange focus for suggesting books, and I am not sure I understand the connection with DRM. DRM are
universally toxic, not just with Amazon, if that is what you enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

MobileRead has forums for book recomendations and discussions.

https://www.mobileread.com/